# How to Download videos from Windows App (MS store app) for Offline Viewing?

Tags: web-scraping, uwp, screen-scraping, video-capture, microsoft-store

Need help geeks, I have a subscription to an academy providing online video lectures for my course. The videos can only be accessed through a Microsoft Store based Windows application (probably a UWP app). However, when offline, I can't take lectures, and the app can't be loaded.The app's functionality appears to be like real-time streaming of lectures and solely depends on an internet connection.

I have tried *IDM, 4K Downloader, and some other downloaders* available on the internet to download the videos, but none can access or capture links from the app. I also tried *screen recording* but recorded video shows blank screen.

Is there a solution to this?

PS: I have paid fees for the course and have access until qualification membership. However, I face difficulty in viewing lectures when I am at home, which is in a backward village area with very low-quality internet facilities.